# adding migration to heroku forces reset?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake, rails-migrations

Every time I add a migration to a model, heroku seems to be unaware of that only until I do heroku rake db:reset / pg:reset

What is the procedure I must to to add for instance a :last_name to a user model and that I won't have to reset the DB afterwards?

the actions I know are:

```
rails generate migration add_lastname_to_users last_name:string
```

and then

```
git push heroku
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Am I missing something?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot about this question..

after `rake run db:migrate` you must do `heroku restart` for the schema changes to take affect.

Answer (score 1):

yep, try `heroku run rake db:migrate`

note, you need to use `heroku run` on latest stacks

the advantage is that you can chain rake tasks, i.e.

`heroku run rake db:migrate rake db:seed rake db:whatever`

without needing myriad `&&`'s

Comment: ps - I should really check that you are on Cedar stack before answering, but I'm just guessing because this is tagged Rails3

Comment: hmm.. well after doing heroku stack I get  aspen-mri-1.8.6
* bamboo-mri-1.9.2
  bamboo-ree-1.8.7
  cedar (beta) Does that mean I have cedar or bamboo?

Comment: Yes you are on bamboo so `heroku run` is not valid there. My bad. If you are plannign on using rails 3.1, then I would recommend being on Cedar. Heroku advise that you can't migrate from [Bamboo to Cedar](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar#migrating_from_bamboo_to_cedar) per se, rather you need to create a new app on Cedar and push to it. Heroku's docs are improving every day. Here's the [Cedar+Rails3.0](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) guide, and here's their [Cedar+Rails3.1](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar) guide.

Comment: PS - before you go off and modify your app, can you push some code to github? I don't mind looking at it, just incase there is another problem

Comment: I changed to cedar (after some issues) but now again, after I add a new migration and run heroku run rake db:migrate and call something involving that migration I get errors. After reset they are fixed.. This is a problem to erase the db after each change..

Comment: This is very strange indeed. If your app is simple enough to get running then I will happily clone it from github if you put it up there and give it a look over...